# How to convert text to number in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

All examples I see they convert text to number but the content is a number in text format. I need to create numbers for emails so I can use that as a unique id.

What I need is to go from: test@example.com to a unique number.

Comment: There re many ways to accomplish this from very simple solution like pnuts has offered, to much more complicated ways, all dependant on your use and need. if you have the same email address in two different cells should it have the same Id, or a different id?

Answer (score 0):

More detail on pnuts solution.

Column A has your e-mails.
Column B has `=row()`

C1 has `=if(iserror(vlookup(A1,$A$1:B1,2,0)),B1,vlookup(A1,$A$1:B1,2,0))`

Drag the formula down.

Column C will contain the row number if the address hasn't been listed above, and the row of the first instance if it has been listed.  If your emails don't start in row 1 (such as if you have headers or something), then you'll have to edit all the 1's the the first row of your table with e-mails and place the first formula in that row of column c.

So maybe `C3` would have `=if(iserror(vlookup(A3,$A$3:B3,2,0)),B1,vlookup(A3,$A$3:B3,2,0))`

Comment: Thanks gipinani.  That's cleaner and educational for me.

Answer (score -2):

Write below line in any of the cell in Excel

```
=VALUE("2.0")
```

This will return the conversion of text(string) to number. Select Function from MenuBar (I think its in Insert tab) for other functions.

Comment: That doesn't work for the email strings he's asking about, only numbers in text format.